# Layers in MS Dynamics CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have solution A, and I have solution B which has components added to it from solution A which have been modified and saved into solution B.

If I now create a solution C with components from solution A, will this be a fresh branch of solution A, or will the modifications in solution B appear in solution C?

Comment: The solution is just a grouping of components.  If you change the Account Entity, then any solution that has the Account entity will have that change, regardless of if you made your change within that solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this work is all being done in a single environment where the solutions are unmanaged, then modifications from solution B will appear in solution C.

Comment: What if you modify solution C, will those modifications appear in solution B?

Comment: Yes, when you are working with unmanaged solutions its worth thinking about them as a Venn diagram. The biggest circle is the default solution, within that circle, you will have smaller circles for each of your solutions. Where they overlap they share components and changes made in one will affect the other.